# Is it bad programming practice to store objects of type Foo into a static array of type Foo belonging to Foo in their construction?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, static

Say I wanted to store objects statically inside their own class. Like this:

```
public class Foo  
{  
    private static int instance_id = 0;  
    public static List<Foo> instances = new List<Foo>();

    public Foo()  
    {  
        instances[instance_id++] = this;  
    }  
}
```

Why?

- I don't need to create unique array structures outside the class (one will do).
- I want to map each object to a unique id according to their time of birth.
- I will only have one thread with the class in use. Foo will only exist as one set in the program.

I did searching, but could find no mention of this data structure. Is this bad practice? If so, why? Thank you.

{please note, this question is not specific to any language}

Comment: "Unethical?" I don't know what that means. I think it's bad practice. Your static class is essentially a global, which I would definitely flag in a code review. If you want a singleton, then use a [singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). Also, you probably should make `instances` private, and provide a `get` accessor. Finally, I strongly suspect that your question will be closed as "primarily opinion based."

Comment: Thank you for the input. To respond: *unethical is just my word for bad programming practice. :) *I agree that the global-ness of my class array access is dangerous because it remains open for the duration of the thread. *The singleton is useful for when I want to limit instantiation to one object, however I wish to produce multiple objects. *You make a fair point about the access  level of my array, I should control and modify the objects within the class if I want to store them there. A 'get' accessor should be the next step, I will do so. *I was worried about the subjectivity of this q--

Comment: But if the list is `static` then all instances of `Foo` will access the same list. So then there is no benefit to having multiple instances of the class. Unless there are some instance properties and methods in addition to that static list.

Comment: Yes, I will be referencing the objects from outside the class and call public non-static methods on them. I am working on a game, that will probably end up a submition for a college assignment, and this specific class defines bitmap rectangles. I wanted to better encapsulate my data, and I am also storing these objects' data (stripped, mind you) in a quadtree, so I wanted to limit the number of places where I reference the location of said objects. The quadtree stores the location of each object's rectangle and can return an object's id that references said object.

Comment: Now, I could have stored the objects in ONLY the quadtree, and not use a second array, but I need unrestricted access to all objects when I want. I am following the Java model-view-controller architecture and I can't have controller access to my objects unless I store them in open access. My objects exist as rectangular bitmaps in graphics, but also as a very global level of object that responds to the player and other AI.

Comment: a perfect fit for CR here on SE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of potential problems I can see with this setup.

First, since you only have a single array of objects, if you need to update the code so that you have lots of different groups of objects in different contexts, you'll need to do a significant rewrite so that each object ends up getting associated with a different context. Depending on your setup this may not be a problem, but I suspect that in the long term this decision may come back to haunt you.

Second, this approach assumes that you never need to dispose of any objects. Imagine that you want to update your code so that you do a number of different simulations and aggregate the results. If you do this, then you'll end up having your giant array storing pointers to objects you're not using. This means that you'll (1) have a memory leak and (2) have to update all your looping code to skip over objects you no longer care about.

Third, this approach makes it the responsibility of the class, rather than the client, to keep track of all the instances. In some sense, if the purpose of what you're doing is to make it easier for clients to have access to a global list of all the objects that exist, you may want to consider just putting a different list somewhere else that's globally accessible so that the objects themselves aren't the ones responsible for keeping track of themselves.

I would recommend using one of a number of alternate approaches:

1. **Just have the client do this.** If the client needs to keep track of all the instances, just have them always create the array they need and populate it. That way, if multiple clients need different arrays, they can do so. You also avoid the memory leak issues if you do this properly.
2. **Have each object take, as part of its constructor, a context in which to be constructed.** For example, if all of these objects are nodes in a quadtree, have them take a pointer to the quadtree in which they'll live as a constructor parameter, then have the quadtree object store the list of the nodes in it. After all, it seems like it's really the quadtree's responsibility to keep track of everything.
3. **Keep doing what you're doing, but using something with weak references.** For example, you might consider using some variation on a `WeakHashMap` so that you do store everything, but if the objects are no longer needed, you at least don't have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I decided that I will do away with the static class array because I will indeed have to manually garbage collect objects in the list and thus need to rewrite said list. It would be easier for me to have the client module control a hash map so I can precisely cut out objects that I want to delete (without the imposed overhead).